# WPF togglebutton having two states

Tags: c#, wpf, togglebutton

Trying to add two states to a button, first click opens a canvas, the second closes the canvas.

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="retailButton" Content="Button" Canvas.Left="203" Canvas.Top="107" Width="327" Height="83" RenderTransformOrigin="0.49,0.398" Visibility="Visible" Opacity="0" Click="retailButton_Click" IsEnabled="True" >
```

not sure about the code behind?

Comment: Give the canvas a Style with a trigger that opens/closes it depending on the value of `retailButton.IsChecked`. [Similar stuff in this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360608/one-popup-for-all-button/40362822#40362822).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use binding and a converter

```
<UserControl.Resources> 
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis" />
</UserControl.Resources>
...
        <Canvas Visibility="{Binding ElementName=ToggleCanvasVisibility, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}}"/>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleCanvasVisibility"/>
```

This is very close to this post: [Binding a Button's visibility to a bool value in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7000819/binding-a-button-visibility-to-bool-value-in-viewmodel)